# How to execute XQuery on all XML documents in the folder

Tags: xquery, basex

I need to make sure a particular node exists in many XML files. I have to switch the context each time I want to query another document.

[image]

Is there any way I can execute XQuery on all documents in the directory without switching the context?

Comment: Would a solution that uses the file api to enumerate and open the files work for you?

Comment: @JonSG yes it would

Comment: An answer to this might be useful to others facing the same situation.  Did you develop/discover a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be a little late, but most probably the following XQuery will do what you wish, it returns the path to each XML-File that does not contain a specific element:

```
let $path := "."
for $file in file:list( $path, true(), '*.xml')
  let $path := $path || "/" || $file
  where not(
    exists(fetch:xml($path)/foo/bar[text() = "Text"])
  )  
return $path
```

If you were only interested if there were XML-files in a specific that do or do not contain a specific element the following query might be useful:

```
declare variable $path := "/Users/michael/Code/foo";

every $doc in file:list($path, true(), '*.xml') (: returns a sequence of file-names :)
              => for-each(concat($path,"/", ?)) (: returns a sequence of full paths to each file :)
              => for-each(fetch:xml#1)          (: returns a sequence of documents :)
satisfies exists(
  $doc/*/*[text() = "Text"]
)
```

Hope this helps ;-)